# Changing appium setting to not have a fresh state of the app in the simulator

Tags: javascript, appium, webdriver-io

I currently have an app i am automating with appium and webdriverio. I am curious if there is any option in appium to change simulator setting to not have a fresh state of the app in the simulator. There is a tutorial that shows up everything you close the simulator or reinstall the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it simply with the help of `desired capabilities`. You have to set `Full reset` as `false` and `no reset` as `true`.  Please have a look.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
 capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
```

This way it simply restart emulator or real device from same state it was closed. It will not uninstall and install client.

Comment: If it serve your purpose then you can accept it as answer.